# excel VBA create report table from list table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build report from external workbooks on servers. Can't use Pivot, it takes too long to load data and refresh.

I have plain table with data, and need to create Matrix type table, where Column B stays as Col B values, and Col C ++, goes to be headers (in row) and data filtered by date in B2. Then count duplicates from data table that match col headers and Col B rows, and put result in cell. And count SUM.

New to VBA, don`t know how to aproach that. Newbie in simple formulas and formatings.

Hope someone can help.

product data:
[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: In the Results sheet, if you fill in column B so each cell has "ordered", "undelivered", you should just bea ble to use `COUNTIFS()`.  What have you tried?

Comment: i have made some code to filter and get data in result sheet, will put it later on, i`m looking for dynamic job, currently i have hard coded cell locations for calculations, data table every day is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `COUNTIFS()` to complete the results table.

In the first sheet, I have named the ranges appropriately (see the grey text at the end, that's what I named that range):

[image]

Then, in the results sheet, simply copy "ordered"/"Undelivered" down, then starting in `D5`, place this formula and fill in your table:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(date,$B$1,orders,$B5,transport,$C5,product,D$3)=0,"",COUNTIFS(date,$B$1,orders,$B5,transport,$C5,product,D$3))
```

[image]

(the red highlighted area is where the formula is filled in).  And of course, if you don't want to see the repeated "ordered"/"undelivered", simply set the font to white.